# Как сделать более одного notify в Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Есть роль, которая ставит небольшой пакет и перезапускает апач:

```
---

- name: install php fpm 5.6
  yum: name=php56-fpm state=latest
  notify: restart httpd
```

А как писать, если мне нужно сделать два notify или больше?

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change):

```
---

- name: install php fpm 5.6
  yum: name=php56-fpm state=latest
  notify:
     - restart httpd
     - restart php56-fpm
```